# Play any audio for given time

Tags: ios, audio, playback

I want to play any file for 6 seconds. Also suppose the audio is bigger then 6 sec the application will play only for 6 sec.and if it is less then 6 sec then play continuously. So is there any inbuilt option from any framework?

Answer (score 0):

[A Simple Way To Play MP3 Audio Files](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/simple-way-to-play-mp3-audio-files)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use an AVAudioPlayer, send a `-stop` message after 6 seconds:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6
                               target:thePlayer selector:@selector(stop)
                                    userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

(Remember to invalidate the timer if the player stops early.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AVAudioPlayer` you can make use of an `NSTimer` as mentioned by @Kenny. Just to add to add to that answer.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6
                               target:thePlayer selector:@selector(stopPlayer)
                                    userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)stopPlayer
{
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

In case the duration of your audio file is less than 6 seconds or your desired limit you should continue to play right? so you must set the `numberOfLoops` for the audio player instance to continue playback. Here is the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW12)